# How does javascript #map work with removing an object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is the below returning undefined? Shouldn't I just get back `[{name:'bug']`?

```
var a= [{name:'dark'},{name:'bug'}]

a.map(function (obj) {
    if (obj.name !== 'dark'){
      return obj
    }
  })

//returns [undefined,{name:'bug}]
```

Comment: I think you're sort of confusing `map` with `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` means you are mapping something for every item in an array. If you do not return anything, it will return `undefined`

If you wish to get certain values based on condition, you should use `.filter`

```js
var a = [{
  name: 'dark'
}, {
  name: 'bug'
}]

var b = a.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.name !== 'dark'
})

console.log(b)
```

#### Usage

- Map: if you wish to get some property of an object from an array of objects.
- Filter: If you wish to get specific values based on a condition. This will return array.
- Find: If you wish to get only first matching value. This will return element and not array.
- forEach: If you wish to loop over array and do specific processing.

**Note:** Most of array functions have compatibility issues and you should check it before using it.

#### References

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array
- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: so there's no way to remove something from an arr with map? I should just use forEach and pop?

Comment: No. And it is not intended for this. If you wish to remove values, use `Array.filter`

Comment: @mangocaptain In general, you should not think in terms of "removing something from an array". You will end up splicing and slicing and popping and just confusing yourself. It's almost always better to think of creating a new array with just the elements you want, which is exactly what `filter` does.

Comment: Nevertheless, you could just insert a splice line in a forEach statement to remove a chosen object

Comment: What compatibility issues?

Comment: @torazaburo, array.map is not supported in IE8, array.find is not supported in any IE. So if OP wishes to support such browsers, he will have to rely on `for` or use polyfill

Comment: IE8 is far past its end of life, and the number of applications which need to or choose to support it is vanishingly small. I hardly think every JS answer on SO needs to add a caveat for browsers stuck back in ES3. AFAIK, not even jQuery 2.0 supports IE8. The majority of applications these days actually specify IE11 or better. Since the OP used `map`, he implicitly is placing himself in an ES5 world. There is a thread on meta which states that *If the question is using ES5, answer with ES5*. `find`, of course, is ES6, and so yes, if you are going to talk about it you should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter like this :

```
var a= [{name:'dark'},{name:'bug'}];
var b = a.filter(item => item.name != 'dark');
console.log(b); // [ { name: 'bug' } ]
```